# Firefox: Youtube Freezes because of failure to query drm device

Tags: firefox, freeze, kde-neon

## The problem:

Youtube keeps freezing on firefox, although it's working fine otherwise. Running youtube shorts will always freeze youtube where as running normal videos freeze it some time and don't freeze it another time, it doesn't seem to be a problem with swap (my ram is 12gb and swap is 8gb), I ran firefox from the terminal it output this

## Logs:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
^CExiting due to channel error.
```

I have tried running youtube on google chrome and it's working fine. The output in ATTENTION seems to be unrelated but I am not sure, the devs at firefox say it's not an issue [(over here)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1744389)

## What I am using?

I am using kde neon from a usb. I have an intel core i5-5300U chip with an integrated graphics card

Comment: If you visit `about:support`, what does it say about GPU #1? If there are more GPUs, please include them, the information should be added to your question.You can also check the troubleshooting mode.

Answer (score 0):

had same issue

- ubuntu 22.4
- firefox v120 from ppa - not snap

and this bug-report helps me:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/2044304

Adding the following the following permissions to /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.firefox fixes the issue:

```
 /sys/devices/pci*/**/{config,revision} r,
 @{PROC}/[0-9]*/**/comm r,
 @{PROC}/[0-9]*/**/oom_score_adj w,
```

the official tips like

- hw-acceleration disabled
- clean new profile without extensions

did not solve it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: is it now right?